# HTML5 sound file player

Tags: ipad, html, mobile-safari, audio

I am trying to make a simple player in HTML5 that will allow the user to select an item from an option list and then play the appropriate sound file.  I am targeting Mobile Safari, primarily.

I am trying to emulate this application I built a while ago in Flash:
http://www.finegardening.com/pguide/pronunciation-guide-to-botanical-latin.aspx

The following code I was able to mostly get to work on my local server, but only in Chrome Dev, and it would crash after playing more than one or two clips.

http://jsfiddle.net/smlombardi/7Wg7Y/

Can anyone give me some ideas on how to accomplish this?  That is select an item, load the sound file associated with that item, play the file onClick with a button, then discard the file and load another onChange of the list.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this html5 sound library.
http://buzz.jaysalvat.com/

Good Luck.